# Why do I keep getting the name not defined error?

Tags: python

```
def RollTwoDice()
     die1 = random.randint(1,6)
     die2 = random.randint(1,6)
```

*Then here I have the code that displays pictures of dice depending on the numbers rolled*

then:

```
print("Press \'enter\' to roll two dice
input()
myRoll=RollTwoDice
total=die1+die2
print("You rolled a total of",total)
```

Now the displaying of the die works perfectly, the only issue is the last line of code. I get this error;

```
     total = die1+die2

     NameError: name 'die1' is not defined
```

I thought die1 and die2 were being defined when i ran the myRoll=RollTwoDice line? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Take a moment to combine your example into a single working script. Right now you have multiple errors that show that you haven't put the effort into posting something real for us. The goal is something we can cut/paste and try ourselves.

Answer (score 3):

- `RollTwoDice()` doesn't return anything. Add a line at the end of the function that says `return die1, die2`.
- You need to define `die1` and `die2` *outside* of the function, and you need to call it, not just mention it.  Change `myRoll = RollTwoDice` to `die1, die2 = RollTwoDice()`.

Answer (score 2):

Variables `die1`and `die2`are local to the function `RollTwoDice`.  Just add a `return` statement.  You also need to use parentheses to call the function.  You don't need to escape single quotes within double quotes.

```
import random
def RollTwoDice():
  die1 = random.randint(1,6)
  die2 = random.randint(1,6)
  return die1, die2
print("Press 'enter' to roll two dice")
input()
die1, die2 = RollTwoDice()
total = die1 + die2
print("You rolled a total of",total)
```

This should work in python3.

Search for "variable scope" or "local scope" for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`die1` and `die2` are local variables, their scopes are just in function `RollTwoDice`

Answer (score 0):

Discounting the syntax errors in your post looks like the issue here is that you're defining die1 within the scope of that function. 
Just define die1 and die2 in global scope and the program will run!

Answer (score 0):

Die1 and die2 need to be declared globally or the function rolltwodice should return a list of the individual die
return die1,  die2